# Check if app was bought

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, app-store

I just wanted to ask if there is a way to check if the user actually did buy an app programmatically. I saw how Infinity Blade 3 and other games forced the user to log in to their apple accounts and somehow checked with the store on whether or not the app has been bought. How is this possible to create programmatically? I've searched all over the web just to find how to open up the storkit view from which you can purchase other apps or videos, etc... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to check for the app's receipt and verify it with the AppStore -

```
NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]; // iOS 7+, do not use respondsToSelector as it will report YES for iOS 6 too
```

Here's [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html) on how to verify your receipt.
If the receipt is nil or the url points to a non existent path, you may need to refresh the receipt.
Implement `SKRequestDelegate` and check:

```
NSError* err = nil;
if (![url checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err]){
    SKReceiptRefreshRequest* request = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] initWithReceiptProperties:nil];
    request.delegate = self; /* or your delegate's instance here */
    [request start];
}
....
-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest*)request{
    if([request isKindOfClass:[SKReceiptRefreshRequest class]]){
        // The URL should be available now, if it's not - I guess the app is cracked
    }
}
-(void)request:(SKRequest*)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    ; // This does not mean the app is pirated, use this to schedule the test for later.
}
```

I would disable these checks in debug mode (and on the simulator).
You may want to check this project - [VerifyStoreReceiptiOS](https://github.com/rmaddy/VerifyStoreReceiptiOS) for verifying your receipts.

Comment: And if there are no receipts then the app is cracked? Also, does this action cause the AppStore login alert to pop up, where the user will enter his account creds? Because that is how infinity blade 3 protected it's app from cracks...

Comment: Looks like the fetch triggers the apple id login, ignore my previous comment.

Comment: Is your code valid ? I mean I put it in my project and after signing in my apple ID , compiler shows `didFailWithError` message , I mean does you code prove that users bought my app before ?

Comment: @Mc.Lover Well, that could be possibly because your app isn't on the App Store, therefore testing the code above is impossible. I haven't yet tested the code above since I still have a lot of features to add to my application before I test out the code above. But iMoses is a trusted user due to the many questions he solves tremendously, so I'd think he'd give code that works. Not to say that it compiled all fine but seems to be an issue only upon running it on the device.