# iOS check if user purchased the app before or no

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have developed an `iOS` application that was a paid app and it was released on `AppStore`. Many users have purchased it and downloaded it from there.

Now we have changed it to be free with some paid features. The problem now is that the past users who have already purchased the app are asked to pay for these new paid features. It shouldn't happen since they already purchased the whole app before.

Moreover, if one of those old users removed the app before new release then installed the new free release, he will be asked to pay for these new features also.

Is there a way to know whether the current `Apple` account has purchased this app - using the `App ID` - before ?

If not, is there a way to check if this app was installed before on the device then removed ?

Comment: long answer: no.

Comment: actually it is possible. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390810/change-paid-app-to-free-but-know-if-user-previously-purchased-it or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088768/check-if-app-was-bought

Comment: .. or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924123/how-to-get-the-original-application-version-the-first-purchased-version-number